# Statistics Question - Given probability - Diseases positive testing.

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the probability of having TB somewhere is 0.05.

A test for TB yields a positive results 80% of the time for people who have TB and 10% positive for people who do not.

Consider person A being tested positive. What is the probability that she does in fact have TB?

My attempt so far:

If we let P be the the probability of it testing positive and TB being the probability of having the diseases.

We need to find the probability P(D|P). How do I find that?

Thanks a bunch for any help! Statistics really is not my strong suit unfortunatly :(.

Comment: "let P be the the probability of it testing positive...find the probability P(D|P)". What you want is the _event_ of testing positive, call it E so you don't get confused with so many P's. See Bayes formula for how to calculate P(D|E) from P(E|D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(D|P) = \frac{ P(P|D) P(D)}{P(P)} = \frac{P(P|D) P(D)}{P(P|D) P(D) +P(P|¬D) P(¬D)} = \frac{0.8 × 0.05}{0.8×0.05 +0.1×0.95} = 0.296$$